# Are forward-slashes in `PathBuf::from("dir1/dir2/dir3")` cross-platform-OK?

Tags: windows, rust

In writing platform-agnostic Rust code, are slashes for directory separators OK:

`let path = PathBuf::from("dir1/dir2/file")`

or is it better to use:

`let path: PathBuf = ["dir1", "dir2", "file"].iter().collect();`

I don't have a Windows system to test on, but if we have to support Windows in future I don't want to have to go back and fix all the slashes. I don't know what will happen with `PathBuf::from("dir1/dir2/file")` on Windows: will something convert to backslashes?

Both styles seem present in the docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/index.html#simple-usage

Comment: I think Windows accepts forward slashes, but I'm not sure whether there might be some edge cases where it causes issues. Personally, I avoid manually typing path separators just to be safe.

Comment: I believe Powershell allows `/ ` to be used as path separators. Not sure about other places.

Comment: The Win32 API itself accepts `/` allright, and Rust stdlib does too. But if you use that path, for example, as argument to a command line program, then you may get into trouble. Instead of swapping all `/` for a constant, that is a nightmare, consider just using [std::fs::canonicalize()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/fn.canonicalize.html) before passing the path to any external party. I think it will just do _the right thing_.

Comment: @rodrigo `canonicalize` is a bit tricky, and it also requires the file to already exist

Comment: There's GitHub Actions if you ever are looking for a quick disposable Windows machine to test some of this stuff.